# How do I open up Command Prompt and run a CasperJS script via C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, visual-studio, casperjs

**Solution:** I rebooted my computer and it worked. It must have not picked up on the change to the PATH that I executed before building this project.

---

I have a CasperJS script that I need to run from my C#.NET Visual Studio Application.  I can open up CMD and run the script no problem from Start > Run > CMD, but if I open CMD through my Visual Studio application, I can't run the scripts.

Here is a picture.

The one on the left is the Command Prompt initiated from the application, the right is the other.
[image]

sorry about the image, here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuJsg.png

This is all the button does.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe");
}
```

I added CasperJS to my PATH environment variables and I'm able to run the script no problem, until I use Visual Studio to open Command Prompt, then it loses the path to CasperJS.  I ran the PATH command and CasperJS is there, but if I run the PATH command in the Command Prompt that was opened by my application, its not there.

[image]

link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGYq.png

Comment: Looks like CasperJs command not available in your PATH environment variable. Can check PATH command in CMD and verify Casper JS exists?

Comment: I added CasperJS to my PATH environment variables and I'm able to run the script no problem, until I use Visual Studio to open Command Prompt, then it loses the path to CasperJS.  I ran the PATH command and CasperJS is there, but if I run the PATH command in the Command Prompt that was opened by my application, its not there.

Comment: Thats is strange I tried with Java, and it is working fine.

Comment: This is pretty frustrating. Its like its grabbing two seperate PATH's.

Comment: I added another image to show you what the path commands are showing for the cmds

Comment: Rebooted PC and the path corrected itself. Thanks for the help Anuraj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooted PC and it corrected the PATH.